# Converting Eclipse AppEngine Project to Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven, gwt

I have a project that has released a few versions to AppEngine already.  Watching the sessions at I/O and the Cloud Platform events has me excited for push-to-deploy and live breakpoints.  Add extra bonuses like Maven's ability to manage dependencies, and Maven is really attractive for this project.

The project is just an Eclipse project, created via New > Google > Web Application Project in Eclipse.  Currently it's just using the built-in Eclipse/Google Plugin build.

I've gotten the following done:

- Ran m2eclipse conversion.
- Moved source into Maven-standard directory structure.
- Maven-available dependencies removed from lib/ folder and added to Maven.
- Maven Build and Maven Unit Test both succeed.
- Ran mvn eclipse:eclipse to re-build config, and then re-added GAE SDK to the
  Java Build Path so the Google Plugin for Eclipse can see it.

I'm still having a few issues, though...

1. Debugging/running locally causes java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
   javax/mail/MessagingException in the console output.
2. I have tried with javax.mail dependency included, but I'm 90% sure
   since it is in the GAE SDK I should not have it explicitly listed.
3. Once service is running, I get a 404 for both the main application
   and the admin console.  Presuming this is related to the above, but
   not 100% sure.
4. We use a secondary AppEngine instance for testing "live" before
   deploying to production.  Is there a way to set the branch for
   push-to-deploy so we aren't merging back to master in advance of
   release?
5. Is there a reason that GWT 2.6.1 is available through Maven, but not
   through the Google Eclipse repo? Also, where do GWT .properties files go for Maven?  Anything I
   need to convert there?

Sorry for some questions that seem a little basic, but this is my first dance with Maven, and I'm flying solo on this project.  (My PM is not a developer by trade, and my intern doesn't know Maven either.)

EDIT: Forgot to post the pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.stripped</groupId>
  <artifactId>bogus</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.3</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Stuff</name>
  <properties>
    <appengine.target.version>1.9.15</appengine.target.version>
    <gwt.target.version>2.6.1</gwt.target.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>          
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <runTarget>index.html</runTarget>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <webResources>
                    <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.target.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.target.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
        <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
        <artifactId>objectify-gwt</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Unit Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

EDIT2:

I noticed the debug configuration was pointing to 
    -war [AbsPath]src\main\webapp
...which does not have a lib/ folder.  I changed it to 
    -war [AbsPath]target\bogus-3.9.6
and no longer get the NoClassDefFoundError!

However, I'm now getting this, the first exception I get if I deploy to AppEngine.

```
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Nov 21, 2014 12:10:37 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader checkWorkingDirectory
WARNING: Your working directory, ([...]workspace\bogus\src\main\webapp) is not equal to your 
web application root ([...]workspace\bogus\target\bogus-3.9.6)
You will not be able to access files from your working directory on the production server.

Nov 21, 2014 12:10:37 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
Nov 21, 2014 12:10:38 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer transform
SEVERE: Unable to instrument com.bogus.server.services.MailHandlerFilter. Security restrictions may not be entirely emulated.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1790
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:181)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer.rewrite(Transformer.java:133)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer.transform(Transformer.java:113)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:216)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:81)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:255)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:288)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:522)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1104)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)

Nov 21, 2014 12:10:38 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed MailHandlerFilter: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 4022320623 in class file com/bogus/server/services/MailHandlerFilter
Nov 21, 2014 12:10:38 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@77fcc757{/,[...]workspace\uswr_gwt\target\uswr_gwt-3.9.6}: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 4022320623 in class file com/bogus/server/services/MailHandlerFilter
Nov 21, 2014 12:10:38 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@7403695c: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 4022320623 in class file com/bogus/server/services/EcontrollerMailHandlerFilter
Nov 21, 2014 12:10:38 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error starting handlers
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 4022320623 in class file com/bogus/server/services/EcontrollerMailHandlerFilter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:216)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:81)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:255)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:288)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:522)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1104)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
```

Comment: Care to show your POM? At least the minimal configuration showing the dependencies in question is necessary to help troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Done.  I removed some Apache Commons dependencies, and two external libraries that are self-contained.

Comment: To confirm that you have the necessary class(es) in the classpath, you can use a tool like `jarexplorer` to load all the jars in the classpath to its working set and try finding the `MessagingException` class. Because, there's no way this class would have had problems getting initialized/loaded if it was available in the classpath.

Comment: For AppEngine, MessagingException is in appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.15.jar.  That jar is provided via Maven, is in the WEB-INF in target/, and is in the .classpath for the project.

It's not making it to Jetty, though.  Meaning either the classpath isn't being passed around properly, or there's a third location (besides pom.xml for Maven and .classpath for Eclipse) that it needs set.

Comment: Looks like the `appengine`'s sdk contains a repackaged bundle of `asm` library? Can you check for the compatibility of the version of the `asm` that is bundled with your version of the `java`?